# Executing CPU heavy HTTP requests asynchronously in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node app that uses node canvas to generate a dot plot graph from a file.

I'm having a problem with requests blocking each other. These requests involve CPU heavy looping through of large arrays (close to 1 million in length).

For example, I have one request which does some analysis on the file. This involves looping through an array with a length of 800k+ and calculating the mean value.

```
app.get('/api/get/statistics', function(req, res) {

    // Promise here which gets files and loops through and calculates mean

});
```

Another request loops through the same array and creates a graph and returns to the UI.

```
app.get('/api/canvas', function(req, res) {

    // creates the graph

});
```

On their own, the first request takes about 40 seconds and the second about 13 seconds. But when I make the requests at the same time, the second request will take about 53 seconds (and sometimes times out) as it's being queued.

Is there a way around this? I was thinking I could use child processes, perhaps with [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads). But it seems like from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813605/how-to-get-child-process-to-write-to-an-http-response-in-node) it might not be possible with seperate HTTP requests.

Note: I don't want to do these in the same request. Most of the time I'm firing off multiple requests to the '/api/canvas' endpoint to create different graphs. So I'm basically wondering is it possible to execute these CPU heavy requests at the same time?

Comment: You should redesign your architecture. I had to do something similar and the best solution for me is to just trigger the start of a *job* via ajax that then runs on the server. On the client side, you can see the status of this job and you're notified when the job is ready (via WebSockets). I also moved the heavy work into a separate node thread that runs parallel.

Comment: Off topic. Calculating avg for 1M records shouldn't be anywhere close to 40 seconds. It should be like 40ms on modern CPU https://jsfiddle.net/xttcro2f/1/

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: He's making 1M HTTP requests, not merely adding numbers. I don't know about you but my network can't really do that in 40ms

Comment: @slebetman 1M HTTP requests? Where do you get this? OP says he is looping through array with values calculating avg " I have one request ... This involves looping through an array with a length of 800k+ and calculating the mean value" Which is "merely adding numbers".

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes, one request. Its a bit more complex - its a 2D array. 2 points represent x,y on a graph. I then check if these are within a polygon or multiple polygons, getting mean for each polygon & combination of polygons

Comment: @Mark I see. Than since javascript is single threaded you'd need to spawn another process that does heavy lifting as Maxim's answer says/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatch the calculation to another process to make it asynchronous and prevent it from blocking the NodeJS thread as it does now.

One way is to use [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) and communicate with it via [`child.send`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback). If the child process is not a NodeJS process, comminicate via its `stdin` and `stdout` for requests and responses correspondingly, `stderr` for errors.